# Moving an ItemView from one CollectionView in another without deleting it, best practice?

Tags: marionette

I'm building a dashboard builder and view interface with Marionette. I have some views from legacy code that are pretty heavyweight(large reports) and the html is thus pre-constructed on the server.

I have a Marionette CollectionView for each row in the dashboard which contains an ItemView for each widget that was dragged onto the row during dashboard building.

When the user moves a widget from one row to another I want to avoid deleting the view and having to reconstruct it (because it would be a lot of unnecessary dom manipulation) but instead want to just detach the element from one(row) CollectionView and add it to another. What's the best practice for accomplishing this with CollectionViews in Marionette?

It seems by default moving a item across CollectionViews would destroy the view/model from one and re-instantiate/re-render it in the other.

The concern I have is that the tablereport in the DOM that would be moving from one collection to another is not original Marionette/Backbone template generated View, it would be just a predefined DOM element we set as the view's el.

The tablereport DOM element has lots of children elements with events associated with it via legacy code not the Backbone view events array nor via Backbone's listenTo calls. So destroying the DOM tablereport element is what we need to avoid to preserve those events, we just want to relocate it in the DOM.

Whats the best way to handle this functionality efficiently in Marionette.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options spring to mind, but the fact that your event-binding code is not easily callable means you'll probably want to use the jQuery detach() method to keep all your events bound when you remove an element.

One option is to cache your view elements as you build them:
- write a view factory which you delegate to in the buildItemView method of your CompositeView.
- have your factory cache the elements for the views it creates against the model.cid of the model that is passed in as the first parameter to the buildItemView method.
- when your factory method is called, retrieve the element from the cache if it exists, call detach() on it, and set it as the ItemView's element.
- override the render method on the view to stop it from rebuilding the html
- move the model from one CollectionView's collection and put it into the other CollectionView's collection, and Marionette will then build your view as described above and insert the element (with events still bound) into the DOM.

Instead of doing the above, you could, assuming you know which ItemView has been dropped:
- remove the ItemView from the first CollectionView's children container (this is a Backbone.Babysitter instance, I believe, and there is documentation for it)
- detach the ItemView's element
- insert the ItemView's element into its new place in the DOM
- insert the ItemView into the second CollectionView's children container
- remove the model from the first CollectionView's collection
- add the model into the second CollectionView's collection silently, which prevents the CollectionView from triggering its normal behaviour of building a new view, rendering it and inserting it.

The first way is probably more elegant as you are still letting Marionette do its thing, but just altering the building, rendering and inserting of the ItemViews. The second way is less complex, but means you have to manually keep everything in sync yourself - essentially doing what Marionette would normally do behind the scenes and stopping it from 'interfering', so to speak.